# Create np array or pd data-frame filled with symbols

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there any way to create np.array or pd.df filled with symbols, for example:

```
column1
+            
/           
*           
%           
$            
&
```

or something like this:

```
column1
(+&$)
( 
//
```

So idea is to put any symbol (I need) in df or np.array .... or maybe this is not doable.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `symbols`?  Those look like strings.  Python has variables and objects - like strings, lists, dataframes, and arrays.  It does not have "symbols"

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of random single character symbols you can use `np.random.choice`, and perhaps get the symbols from the `string` library:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
from itertools import permutations, chain

pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(string.punctuation), (2, 4)))

   0  1  2  3
0  <  '  [  #
1  ;  ^  !  ]
```

---

If you want to get a random length string of characters, you can use `itertools` to create those possibilities and then again choose from that list. This will be heavily weighted toward producing `MaxChars` length strings since there are many more permutations, while there are only 32 possibility for single punctuation choices.

```
MaxChars = 4
choices = [''.join(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(permutations(list(string.punctuation), r) 
           for r in range(1, MaxChars+1))]

pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(choices,(2, 4)))

      0     1     2     3
0  #[:-  #{:&  }&^~   [%_
1  /@&>  .;\~  |>~"  ?/^)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I would like to have possibly to chose which characters I would like to put, so no random ones.

Comment: @user16454053 then instead of `list(string.punctuation)` use a list of your characters like `['+', '&',]`